# how to validate javascript message on client side from resource file?

Tags: asp.net, resources

I'm struggling to work out how I can validate javascript message on client side from resource file?

I tried using the code below in my application, and it works in all pages except the login page.

```
<script type="text/java script" language="java script">
    var jsVar_USERNAME_REQ_JS_MSG = '<%=Resources.CionResources.USERNAME_REQ_JS_MSG %>'; //here not getting value
</script>

function Validate() {     
    var adminUsr =document.getElementById('TabContainer1_tabPnlAdmin_txtAdminName');

    if (adminUsr.value == "") {
        alert(jsVar_USERNAME_REQ_JS_MSG); 
        adminUsr.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: I think you should add your javascript function into script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case where I need to read from resource file inside the JS, So i did a call to a web method. check the code

```
function GetGlobalResourceObject(message) {
    var ResourceMessage = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: MyGlobalResourceWebServiceUrl + 'GetGlobalResource',
        data: "{Message: '" + message + "'}",
        async: false
    }).responseText;
    return ResourceMessage.split("\"")[3];
}
```

the web Method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string GetGlobalResource(string Message)
    {
        return JavaScriptResources.ResourceManager.GetObject(Message).ToString();

    }
```